# SQL - select linking data without a while loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a problem and so far the only solution I can think of is to use a while loop with a select statement but I am looking for an alternative. The situation is that one table used does not use update statements for record keeping, when a record is updated a new record is inserted with the information and a new primary key is assigned. My task is using any primary key to be able to pull up the history of previous keys, this is going to be handled through a new table consisting of three columns, table_PK, updatedFrom_id, and updatedTo_id.

Anyone have any ideas how to avoid the use of a while loop to select all the id's that are related to each other? The can appear in either column but if there has not been an update wouldn't appear in either, and there is no limit as to how many times it can be updated and the statement should be able to retrieve both what is was updated from and if it has been updated what it has been updated to.

Thanks in advance for any help!

update info:

table

```
UpdateLinking
```

columns:

```
UpdateLinking_PK,
UpdatedFrom_id,
UpdatedTo_id
```

example data:

```
UpdateLinking_PK UpdatedFrom_id UpdatedTo_id
77              11             22
78              22             33
79              33             44
80              44             55
81              55             66
```

Both UpdateFrom and UpdateTo are keys from a separate table, could really add an update to column in that table but due to the size and that it will not be used so much will be keeping updates listed separately.
I would like to enter in an UpdateFrom or UpdateTo id and return both updatedFrom and updatedTo. If the Id parameter entered is in updatedTo I would like to check if it is in an updatedFrom column and follow it until the last UpdatedTo id does not appear in an updatedFrom column and vice versa.

The result set for entering any of the id's above should return everything in the UpdatedFrom_id and everything in the UpdatedTo_id columns.

If a row was added:

```
UpdateLinking_PK UpdatedFrom_id UpdatedTo_id
82                  88              111
```

This should be excluded if the parameterId passed was 44

Comment: Please post the schema, some sample contents and what would you like to see as a result of the query.

Comment: Please post it as an update to your post, not as a comment

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH    q (id) AS
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   id = @myid
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  updatedFrom_id
        FROM    q
        JOIN    history
        ON      updatedTo_id = id
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    q
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using recursive CTE?

Comment: you should have added this as a comment rather than answer and not if someone has already answered it before you post.

Answer (score 0):

The following query in SQL Server 2012 does what you want:

```
select u.table_Pk,
       lag(UpdatedId) over (partition by u.table_Pk order by UpdatedId) as UpdatedFrom_Id,
       u.updatedId as UpdatedTo_Id
from updates u;
```

This version assumes that the `UpdatedId` columns are inserted in order, because you do not mention a datetime field (or other field) that can be used to define "previous".

Prior to SQL Server 2012, the `lag()` function was not available.  Here is a replacement:

```
select u.table_Pk,
       (select top 1 UpdatedId
        from updated u2
        where u2.table_Pk = u.table_Pk and u2.UpdatedId < u.UpdatedId
        order by u2.UpdatedId desc
       ) as UpdatedFrom_Id,
       u.updatedId as UpdatedTo_Id
from updates u;
```